# How to Activate a Workbook using a variable workbook name?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and need some help with my code. I am using Excel and  `Application.GetOpenFilename` to prompt users to select a file to open. As I copy data from one file to another, I am trying to Activate the workbook what was opened by the `GetOpenFilename` application.

I am running VBA code from my Primary Workbook and here's what my code looks like.

Open import file

```
strGetFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Open Import Workbook")
Workbooks.Open strGetFilename
```

For this example, let's assume that the file selected to open is Workbook2, I then select data from a table in Workbook2 and copy it.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("table1").Range.Select
   Selection.Copy
```

I now paste the data into my primary Workbook

```
Windows("PrimaryWorkbook.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
              :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Here is where I am getting tripped up. I want to go back to Workbook2 in order to copy other tables/sheets or to be able to perform other data edits and I don't want the file name to be hardcoded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign it to a variable

```
Sub x()

Dim wb As Workbook, strGetFilename As String
strGetFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Open Import Workbook")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strGetFilename)

MsgBox wb.Name

End Sub
```

And read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) on how to avoid using Select/Activate.

You can then use

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: This worked beautifully and most important, thank you for directing me to the thread regarding avoiding Select/Activate. That thread helped me better understand DIM & Set and now my crawl has turned into a walk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'Set'

```
Set fileVariable = Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & fileName)
```

You can then refer to the variable with fileVariable.Range("A1").select.

It is generally better to avoid selecting and activating. You can directly code

```
.range("A1").value2 = .range("B1").value2
```

to copy and paste.